# Workflow not working for a particular User(Even if User is Owner of Site)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am Using SharePoint 2013 , Workflow Manager 1.0 Configured.
When Sub Site is Created  We call Workflow using `StartWorkflow` method using C# code.
Workflow is working fine for all user except one.
For that particular user, when i start workflow, my workflow goes to Suspended Stage.
Even though user is having Full Control access on Site.
Could you Please help.

> "Error message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not
> have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}

Comment: Can you please check the error when workflow is in suspended stage and add it to your question? it will be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the user have enough permission for subsite or entire site collection?

You could try to create a workflow with elevated permissions.

References:

[Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo)

[SharePoint 2013 workflow app step and app permissions](http://www.benprins.net/2017/01/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-app-step-and-app-permissions/)